# Quicksort implementation in C?

Tags: c, quicksort, qsort

I really like the `qsort` function in C. It's so easy to use and allows me to procrastinate learning C++ template types. I have a few questions about this:

- Is the algorithm used always a quicksort or is it compiler-implementation-dependent?
- Would you recommend using this function or is there a real benefit to templates?
- Are there any things I should watch out for to avoid security problems/segfaults?

Comment: there's no shame in sticking with C if your application is written in C. But if everything is written in C++ and you are just using C features where C++ confuses you, you may as well just learn C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the algorithm used always a quicksort or is it compiler-implementation-dependent?

It is implementation dependent.

> Would you recommend using this function or is there a real benefit to templates?

C does not have templates.  If you need a generic sorting function in C, then `qsort` is a good choice.

If you are going to use C++, then you should use `std::sort`, which is much easier to use correctly and gives type safety.

> Are there any things I should watch out for to avoid security problems/segfaults?

If you use the function improperly (for example, if you pass it incorrect parameters or if your comparison function has bugs in it), then your program might well crash (or might otherwise perform incorrectly).  Of course, this isn't specific to `qsort`; this is true for anything used in a program.